# Doctrine 2 having statement and relationship

Tags: doctrine-orm, query-builder

Im trying to build a query to get all products with available colors:

```
    $qb->select('p', 'pcl')
       ->from('Entity\Product', 'p')
       ->leftJoin('p.availableColors', 'pcl', 'WITH'));
```

Also I want to get only products having only one specific color:

```
$qb->having($qb->expr()->eq('pcl.id', '1'));
```

but in response i got only one color (id = 1) instead of a full array. How I can build this query to get all colors appended to products? AvailableColors is ManyToMany relationship to other Entity.

Comment: May you post a schema of the tables and the entities class?